# Show Hide button, atleast one checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

When I check one or many boxes it shows the buttons "btns"
but if i uncheck one it hides them, how do I get it to stay 
if one or many checkbox is still checked

```
<input type='checkbox' class='checklist' name='id[]' value='$id' />
<input type='checkbox' class='checklist' name='id[]' value='$id' />
<input type='checkbox' class='checklist' name='id[]' value='$id' />
<input type='checkbox' class='checklist' name='id[]' value='$id' />

$(".btns").hide();

$(".checklist").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".btns").show();
    } else {
        $(".btns").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the amount of checked checkboxes. If it's length is `0` - hide the element, if not - show it.

```js
$(".checklist").click(function() {
  $('.btns').toggle( $(".checklist:checked").length > 0 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' class='checklist' name='id[]' value='$id' />
<input type='checkbox' class='checklist' name='id[]' value='$id' />
<input type='checkbox' class='checklist' name='id[]' value='$id' />
<input type='checkbox' class='checklist' name='id[]' value='$id' />

<p class='btns' hidden>btns</p>
```

Comment: There is a specific jquery method for this *`.toggle()`*, so `$('.btns').toggle( $(".checklist:checked").length > 0 );`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".checklist").click(function() {
var check_count=$(".checklist:checked");
if(check_count.length>0){$(".btns").show();}
else{$(".btns").hide();}
});
```

It check if any of checklist check so show .btns else hide it